# GeoPoint and current Location

Tags: android, location, geopoints

how I can get current GeoPoint from my location.
I am on :
Longitude: 21.760029
Latitude: 54.035795

But when I use getLatitude(), I have 54.0
but I want 54.035795.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method for converting a latitude, longitude pair to a `GeoPoint` object:

```
public static GeoPoint convert(double latitude, double longitude)
{
    int lat = (int)(latitude * 1E6);
    int lng = (int)(longitude * 1E6);

    return new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
}
```